# double free or corruption when implement binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

update:

add more code as asked.pasted to the end of question. Thanks everyone who stops.

current code is fine to delete a leaf, but come to Root, it can not delete.

====
update:
I revise the code, change removeRootMatch to

```
tmp = Root;
Root = tmp->Right; 
tmp->Right = NULL;
delete tmp;
```

and no error but it does not delete the Node.

=====

The program is simple do the following step:

- find min value of a binary tree;
- record the min value in a vector;
- delete the node with min value in the tree;
- repeat 1-3 till the tree is empty.

I have removeNode()function, which will call removeRoot function(check code below),if the one needed to be removed is Root. But I have trouble with this function. I am doing some debug and found it is something wrong with removeRootMatch function. It give an error when run. the error I got is The error I got is `*** glibc detected *** ./bintree: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000727060 ***`, any one can help me?

The tree is defined as following, language is c++

```
typedef struct myNode* LPNode;
typedef struct myNode Node;
struct myNode
{
  double key;

  LPNode Left; //left subtree
  LPNode Right; //right subtree
};
```

Main part of program is as following:

- nmax is initialed as 0,
- sortedvector is alloacted a vector with space as large as the total nodes in the tree,
- min is initialed as 99999.
- minValue will return the min value of tree.
- compareDouble(a,b) will return 1 `if a < b`,return 2 `if a > b`,return 3 if equal

code as following

```
    void removeRootMatch(LPNode Root)
{
    LPNode tmp = MakeNewNode(Root->key);
    tmp->Left = Root->Left;
    tmp->Right = Root->Right;
    //no child
    if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right == NULL) {

        Root=NULL;
    delete Root;
    } else if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right!=NULL){ //one right child
        //delete Root;
            Root = tmp->Right;
        tmp->Right = NULL;
        delete tmp;
    } else {
        printf("Remove root bug!\n");
    }
}
```

This is the function call removeNode function.

```
//compare double
int compareDouble(double a,double b)
{
    if(a-b<-EPSILON) //a<b
        return 1;
    else if(a-b>EPSILON)//a>b
        return 2;
    else
        return 3;
}


//find the min key in a tree
double minValue(LPNode Root,double min) 
{
    if(Root == NULL)
        return min;
    if(compareDouble(Root->key,min)==1)
        min = Root->key;
    min = minValue(Root->Left, min);
    min = minValue(Root->Right, min);
    return min;
}

//remove root
void removeRootMatch(LPNode& Root)
{
    LPNode tmp = MakeNewNode(Root->key);
    tmp->Left = Root->Left;
    tmp->Right = Root->Right;
    //no child
    if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right == NULL) {
        Root=NULL;
        delete Root;
    } else if(Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right!=NULL){ //one right child

        double k = Root->key;


        Root = tmp->Right;
        tmp->Right = NULL;
        delete tmp;
        //tmp=tmp->Right;
        //Root->Right = NULL;
        //delete Root;
        //Root = tmp;





    } else {
        printf("Remove root bug!\n");
    }
}

//remove a node
void removeMatch(LPNode& Root,LPNode match,bool left)
{
    //no child
    if(match->Left==NULL && match->Right == NULL){
        double k = match->key;
        left==true?
        Root->Left=NULL:
        Root->Right=NULL;
        delete match;
        if(!Root->Left)printf("%f  ",k);
    }
    else if(match->Left==NULL && match->Right!=NULL){//one right child
                double k = match->key;

        left==true?
        Root->Left=match->Right:
        Root->Right=match->Right;
        delete match;
        if(!Root->Left)printf("%f  ",k);
    } else {
        printf("Remove root bug!\n");
    }
}


//delete a node
void removeNode(LPNode Root,double min)
{
    if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)==3){
        removeRootMatch(Root);
    }else if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)==1 && Root->Left != NULL) {

        compareDouble(min,Root->Left->key)==3 ?
        removeMatch(Root,Root->Left,true):
        removeNode(Root->Left,min);
    }else if(compareDouble(min,Root->key)==2 && Root->Right != NULL){

        compareDouble(min,Root->Right->key)==3 ?
        removeMatch(Root,Root->Right,false):
        removeNode(Root->Right,min);
    }else{
        printf("Remove bug1!\n");
    }
}

//call minValue to find the min key
//record the min key in a vector
//call removeNode to delete the Node
//repeat till the tree is empty
void problem1(LPNode Root,double* sortedvector,int& nmax)
{       
    double min;
    //while(Root!=NULL)
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        min = MAX;
        sortedvector[nmax] = minValue(Root,min) ;
        printf("inv%f\n",sortedvector[nmax]);
        removeNode(Root,sortedvector[nmax]);
        nmax++;
    }
    printf("The tree is empty");
}
```

Comment: While I'm pondering, could you run your code under Valgrind (`valgrind --leak-check=full ./bintree`) and see if that helps you narrow down the problem?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I can change my code `tmp = Root;Root = tmp->Right; tmp->Right = NULL;delete tmp;` Then,no error, but the Node is not delete...

Comment: In the case that `Root->Left==NULL && Root->Right == NULL`, you should have segfaulted at `tmp->Left = NULL;`, since you set `tmp->Right = Root->Right;` before the `if`, then you set `tmp = tmp->Right;`. At this point `tmp` is equal to NULL, so when you dereference it with `tmp->Left = NULL;`, your program should have been smitten with a SIGSEGV.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::set`?

Comment: @user657267 yes. There is a reason hard to explain.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I had made some change. no error now, but root is not deleted successfully.

Comment: Can you explain why you're not getting a segfault if there are no children, given that you must be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer before the `delete`? Why are you setting `tmp->Right = NULL;` right before `delete tmp;`? Also, is the root node allocated on the stack?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist i think it is right...

Comment: It can't be. Step-by-step: |1. You clone the `Root` node into `tmp`. |2. **If** `Root->Left` **and**  `Root->Right` are `NULL`, then |3. it follows that `tmp->Left` **and** `tmp->Right` **are also** `NULL`, which means that |4. after `tmp = tmp->Right;`, `tmp` **is** `NULL`, but then |5. in `tmp->Left = NULL;` you dereference `tmp`, a `NULL` pointer! Could you please post the rest of your code, all of it? We can't see the big picture.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I have posted all the code related to delete node, I hope it helps. Thanks for all your time and efforts XXOO

Comment: In `removeRootMatch`: `Root=NULL;delete Root;`. You `NULL` out the root before deleting it, so you're not deleting the root node but rather attempting to delete `NULL`, which has no effect.

Comment: You have a logic error in `removeNode`. You pass the `root` pointer as an argument to the function. It checks whether it matches the key, and if so calls `removeRootMatch`. So far so good. But if the root ISN'T a match, you then call `removeNode(Root->Left,min);` (or `->Right`) recursively, which then _again_ checks for a match, and _might_ end up calling `removeRootMatch` on a node that isn't root!

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist thanks a lot. Already change this, still working on deleteRoot.

Comment: @user3689282 I understand this is a Binary Search Tree? If so why not just find the `min` with `while(cur->Left != NULL){cur = cur->Left} return cur->key;`?

Answer (score 1):

If your function `removeNode` may adjust the Root, then your function is not declared properly.

```
 void removeRootMatch(LPNode Root)
```

You are passing a pointer to Root.  Inside the `removeRootMatch` function, you are working on a copy of the pointer.  So code like this inside of the `removeRootMatch` function:

```
Root = tmp->Right;
    tmp->Right = NULL;
    delete tmp;
```

does not change the Root node when the function returns.

To address this issue, you should pass the Root pointer by reference:

```
 void removeRootMatch(LPNode& Root)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. after I did what you wrote. NO error, but the old Root is not deleted. New Root is changed but old one still in the tree.

Comment: ok.  But the double free error should be gone now, correct?  If it has, then the issue is isolated to your logic of traversing and deleting nodes, and not an issue with passing the parameters properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: There's many problems in the code: `tmp->Right = Root->Right;; if(...Root->Right == NULL) {tmp = tmp->Right; tmp->Left = NULL;`, That's dereferencing a NULL pointer right there

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not sure I understand, but thank u anyway.